# Calculating the determinant of matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The task is to calculate the determinant of following $n\times n$ matrix $A$:

$a_{ij}=2$ if $i=j$.

$a_{ij}=1$ if $|i−j|=1$

and $a_{ij}=0$ otherwise.

I think the $\det A = n+1$. I got that result simply by calculating the determinant for 3x3, 4x4 matrices etc.. but cant figure out how to calculate it if A is $n\times n$ matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show that $\det A_n=2\det A_{n-1}-\det A_{n-2}$, where $\det A_n$ is determinant of $n\times n$ matrix $A_n$. Using induction then you prove your claim.

To see this, consider the following:
$$
A_n=\begin{pmatrix}
  2 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
  1 & 2 & \cdots & 0 \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  0 & 0 & \cdots & 2
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
By expanding the determinant, we get:
$$
\det A_n=\begin{vmatrix}
  2 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
  1 & 2 & \cdots & 0 \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  0 & 0 & \cdots & 2
 \end{vmatrix}_{n\times n}=2\begin{vmatrix}
  2 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
  1 & 2 & \cdots & 0 \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  0 & 0 & \cdots & 2
 \end{vmatrix}_{n-1\times n-1}-1\begin{vmatrix}
  1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
  0 & 2 & \cdots & 0 \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  0 & 0 & \cdots & 2
 \end{vmatrix}_{n-1\times n-1}\\
=2\det A_{n-1}-\det A_{n-2}.
$$
Now with an easy induction, one can prove $\det A_n=n+1$.

Comment: Got it now! Thanks :)